# Synchronizing threads in C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a Forms based application. The UI is handled by a thread.
From the UI Thread, I create 3 threads to perform some processing.

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(() => performprocessing());
Thread t2 = new Thread(() => performprocessing());
Thread t3 = new Thread(() => performprocessing());
```

Now, I want to execute a statement in the UI thread after all the 3 threads finish their execution.So, I did the following:

```
do 
{

} while (t1.IsAlive || t2.IsAlive || t3.IsAlive);
/*--execute statement---*/
```

But I want the UI to remain responsive as well. In this case the UI thread is stuck in the loop until all the three threads finish execution.
How do I perform this?

I read about manual and auto reset events but I am not sure how to use them in this case.
Kindly guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spawning new threads is a bad practice, use a thread pool instead.

```
{
    var t1 = Task.Run(() => doSomething1());
    var t2 = Task.Run(() => doSomething2());
    var t3 = Task.Run(() => doSomething3());

    Task.WhenAll(t1, t2, t3).ContinueWith(t => doSomething4());
}
```

A cleaner approach for .NET 4.5 is to use async/await.

```
async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    var t1 = Task.Run(() => doSomething1());
    var t2 = Task.Run(() => doSomething2());
    var t3 = Task.Run(() => doSomething3());

    await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2, t3);
    doSomething4();
}
```

.NET 4.0 does not define Task.Run() and Task.WhenAll(), use Task.Factory instead.

```
{
    var t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => doSomething1());
    var t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => doSomething2());
    var t3 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => doSomething3());

    Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(new[] { t1, t2, t3}, tasks => doSomething4());
}
```

Comment: .Net 4.0 does not have Task.Run() method. I have to do this with Task.Factory.StartNew() and Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll() methods.

Comment: `Task.Start()`? https://gist.github.com/DanPantry/8296168 excerpt from my current project that uses a Task in 4.0

Comment: @Kaushik Added comments to the answer covering .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 5):

Try using [Barrier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.barrier%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

You need to pass the Barrier instance into your thread, and then use `Barrier.SignalAndWait()` from within the thread. Specify the number of signals you need to proceed in the constructor of Barrier.

Once all signals have been received, the threads that are Waiting will stop blocking.

Answer (score 0):

Use a background worker thread and you can keep the ui responsive and send progress.

```
void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker b1 = new BackgroundWorker();
            BackgroundWorker b2 = new BackgroundWorker();
            BackgroundWorker b3 = new BackgroundWorker();
            b1.RunWorkerCompleted += b1_RunWorkerCompleted;
            b2.RunWorkerCompleted += b2_RunWorkerCompleted;
            b3.RunWorkerCompleted += b3_RunWorkerCompleted;
        }

        void b1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        void b2_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        void b3_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
        }
```

Comment: Please don't use this. Your `if(workerCompleted == 3)` is not thread safe. There could be a possibility of happens-before relationships here. Remember that OP has not given context for how the threads will be used, just that he has a UI thread and 3 separate worker threads.

Comment: Answer updated to remove the threading issue and make it more generic, thank you @dan-pantry

Answer (score -1):

If for whatever reason you don't wish to use Task as mentioned by solmaks then you could use the [Join()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.join%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method which will block until the thread has completed.

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(() => performprocessing());
Thread t2 = new Thread(() => performprocessing());
Thread t3 = new Thread(() => performprocessing());

t1.Join();
t2.Join();
t3.Join();
```

I wouldn't recommend using this on the UI thread however as it could make your application unresponsive.

Comment: This is blocking the UI thread.  The whole point here is to keep the UI responsive.